# 301 Redirect not working on new server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

We are running Apache servers on Linux.

In the `<VirtualHost>` of the Apache Config file (in `/etc/apach2/sites/site.conf`), we have the following rewrite rule:

The purpose of this rule is so that if anyone accesses the site (which can be accessed with multiple domains) attempts to access without `www.` in front, it will 301 redirect to `www.`.  For example, if a user goes to the site `http://example.com`, the rule will 301 redirect to `http://www.example.com`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

We have this same rule setup on other servers and working fine, but for some reason we just can't get it working on this new server.  Restarting Apache is fine etc.. but when we access the site with `example.com`, it is not redirecting to `www.example.com`.

Any suggestions or previous experiences that may give some clues to cause?

=========

Here is an expanded version of the Config for context.

```
<Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

                RewriteEngine on

                # force www
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)$ [NC]
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

                # Bypass images, css, javascript and docs, add your own extensions if needed.
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|txt|pdf|doc|xls|ico)$
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]

                # The ColdBox index.cfm/{path_info} rules.
                RewriteRule ^$ index.cfm [QSA,NS]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.cfm/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,NS]

        </Directory>
```

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Just to clarify, is this directive directly in the server config (or virtual host context) - which you seem to imply? If it is then this directive isn't strictly correct.

Comment: Hi w3dk, yes, mod_rewrite is enabled (other rewrites defined are working fine).  The directive is in the Virtual Host > Directory Context. <VirtualHost *:80> ... <Directory /var/www/etc..>

Comment: Are the other rewrites (that are working) in the same directory context? `FollowSymLinks` must be set when in a directory context. Your regex excludes the hyphen, so presumably your domain names do not include a hyphen? What version of Apache? Have you enabled _debugging_? Check the value of `HTTP_HOST` (eg. assign to an environment variable and check in your code).

Comment: Thanks!  I have pasted the full contexts in there.. FollowSymlinks is there, but in a seperate Directory container.. not sure if this make a difference. I have updated original post with full context.  Apache is Version 2.4.7 (Ubuntu)..  Not sure how to enable debugging.. will investigate on that.. Thanks again !!

Comment: `FollowSymLinks` seems OK (it's in both those directory containers - but as long as it covers the area of the file system then it doesn't matter where it is set). Presumably the other mod_rewirite directives you have are functioning OK (and you've cleared your browser cache) then I can only assume that the `HTTP_HOST` variable is not set as expected perhaps? Try something like `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar?host=%{HTTP_HOST} [R,L]` as the first directive, access `/foo` and what do you see in the address bar?

Comment: I've added the RewriteRule as you suggested.. and that seems to be rewriting fine.  119.9.30.242/foo rewrites to "http://119.9.30.242/bar?host=119.9.30.242" .. This rewrite is directly below the www rewrite..  Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Comment:* I've added the RewriteRule as you suggested.. and that seems to be rewriting fine. 119.9.30.242/foo rewrites to `http://119.9.30.242/bar?host=119.9.30.242`

But in the question you stated:

> ...but when we access the site with `example.com`, it is not redirecting to `www.example.com`

You appear to be accessing the site by an IP address, not a domain name?!

If you are accessing the site by the IP address (not a domain name) then this is obviously not going to redirect, since the preceding `RewriteCond` directive validates the hostname:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)$ [NC]
```

This only allows hostnames that consist of letters and dots, no digits or hyphens (as I mentioned in my previous comment), so this will exclude IP addresses from being redirected. (And correctly so, `http://www.119.9.30.242/` would be invalid.)

**UPDATE:** To allow/redirect domains with digits (and hyphens) then you would need to change the above directive/regex to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9.-]+)$ [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks w3dk.. that was just for example.. also if access the site via domain has the same problem.  Here is a domain that is not redirecting: http://sample.membes3.com.au/.  And interestingly, now that you mention it, http://sample.membes3.com.au/?foo does not redirect to bar..

Comment: `sample.membes3.com.au` - contains a digit (`3`) so this won't be redirected. As mentioned above, your regex excludes digits. `http://sample.membes3.com.au/?foo` also won't redirect, it should be `http://sample.membes3.com.au/foo` (no `?`).

Comment: Spot on.. the issue was the numeric value in the domains!   Thanks w3dk!